# How to disable parameters in SSRS after report execution

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

What I want to do is once the parameters are set and view report is pressed, I want to disable the parameters.That is, once the user has entered the parameters and have ran the report he can not change the parameters now unless he refreshes the whole page.

Can this be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There's not a way to do this directly, but you can accomplish it using a pair of reports at the cost of needing an extra click from your users at certain points:

- Create a "child" version of the report that only has hidden parameters.
- Create a parent version of the report with no data elements that has public parameters.
- Add a link-style textbox to the parent report whose action navigates to the child report using the parent's parameters.
- For convenience, add a link-style textbox to the child report to go back to the parent to re-enter parameters. (optional)
- If desired, include read-only textboxes displaying the parameters on the child report. (optional)

So to your user: They enter the parameters, then click on the link to view the report.  If they want to change the parameters, they need to click on the link to go back, which will force a refresh.